# Java use streams map to return desired JSON Structure

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm new to Java I have an array like below

```
[{'roleName': "driver", "name": "Hub"},{'roleName': "hoc", "name": "Org"},{'roleName': "hubManager", "name": "Hub"}]
```

I have to format the same into below structure

```json
 {
    Org :{
        role : ["hoc"]
    }
    Hub: {
        role :
            ["driver","hubManager"]
        }
 }
```

Please help me how we can do this with Java streams

I have tried the below

```
List<String> roles = roleLevels
                .stream()
                .map(c -> c.getRoleName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But that's not the expected result

Comment: Edit your question to include your attempt as well

Comment: Unclear both input and output data structures. Post minimal and complete sample.

Comment: Inferring the output type to be `Map<String, List<String>>`, you can make use of [Nirmal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67668959/1746118) with a `Collectors.mapping` downstream added to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use groupingBy with downstream Collector:

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = 
    roleLevels.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RoleManager::getName, 
                                             Collectors.mapping(RoleManager::getRole,
                                                                Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

See if below one helps

```
roleLevels.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.getName()));
```

Comment: you would need to additionally perform a downstream `Collectors.mapping` within the `grouping`.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.

```
public class ConverToJSON {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getList());

    final Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> map = new HashMap<>();

    getList().forEach(roleManager -> getRoleNameList(map, roleManager));
    System.out.println(new JSONObject(map));
}

private static void getRoleNameList(Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> map, RoleManager roleManager) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(roleManager.getName(), r -> new HashMap<>())
            .computeIfAbsent("role", rn -> new ArrayList<>())
            .add(roleManager.getRole());
}

private static List<RoleManager> getList(){
    List<RoleManager> roles = new ArrayList();
    roles.add(new RoleManager("driver", "Hub"));
    roles.add(new RoleManager("hoc", "org"));
    roles.add(new RoleManager("hubManager", "Hub"));

    return roles;
}

private static class RoleManager {
    final String role;
    final String name;
    public RoleManager(String role, String name) {
        this.role = role;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RoleManager{" +
                "driver='" + role + '\'' +
                ", hub='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

}

Below is the expected result:

```
{
   "Hub":{
      "role":[
         "driver",
         "hubManager"
      ]
   },
   "org":{
      "role":[
         "hoc"
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have received great answers, but **in case the exact specified JSON output is needed**, there's another thing we need to do.

Let's first create `RoleLevel` class:

```
@Getter
public class RoleLevel {
    String roleName;
    String name;
}
```

Then we can group by name:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonStr = "[{\"roleName\": \"driver\", \"name\": \"Hub\"},{\"roleName\": \"hoc\", \"name\": \"Org\"},{\"roleName\": \"hubManager\", \"name\": \"Hub\"}]";
    List<RoleLevel> roleLevels = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, new TypeReference<List<RoleLevel>>(){});

Map<String, List<String>> nameToRoles = roleLevels.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RoleLevel::getName, Collectors.mapping(RoleLevel::getRoleName, Collectors.toList())));

System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(nameToRoles));
```

But the output JSON is not exactly the expected JSON output:

```
{
    "Hub": ["driver", "hubManager"], // no "role" field
    "Org": ["hoc"]                   // no "role" field
}
```

To fix this we need to create a `Person` class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Person {
    List<String> role;
}
```

then do:

```
Map<String, Person> personToRoles = nameToRoles.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> new Person(entry.getValue())));

System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(personToRoles));
```

Output:

```
{
    "Hub": {
        "role": ["driver", "hubManager"]
    },
    "Org": {
        "role": ["hoc"]
    }
}
```